# Json DateTime Parsing In Android

Tags: android, json, datetime, android-parser

My API Gives This Result:

```
{
    "Posts": [{
        "UseName": "Robert Ray",
        "DateTime": "\/Date(1376841597000)\/",
        "PostText": "Welcome!!\u003cbr\u003eThis Is my Text"
    }]
}
```

I Parse My JSON Like This

```
try {
    Posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

    for(int i = 0; i < Posts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = Posts.getJSONObject(i);
        String post_text = c.getString("PostText"); 

        String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
        Date date = (Date) dateFormat.parse(c.getString("DateTime"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But Its Not Working, what I want is It should calculate the time elapsed since the User posted the Post,
i.e we have to subtract the current data with the date in JSON, and then convert that in Minutes / Hours

Comment: This JSON is malformed. I expect this throws a JSON exception?

Comment: yes it throws exception!! can you please help me fixing the issue?

Comment: i have corrected the Json, Please have a look and help if possible @popovits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I hope that you find this usefull:

```
String ackwardDate = "/Date(1376841597000)/";
//Dirty convertion
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toGMTString()); //Prints 18 Aug 2013 15:59:57 GMT
```

But I'm saying, that date format in your JSON It's really ackwards, take the example of [google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts#events_resource), for a correct, standar, parsed JSON.

Comment: Thanks It Worked!! if possible please let me know how to convert the time In AM/PM Format and what if i have to convert it in other Time Zones.

Comment: You know, this solution is not perfect. Let's say you get the string in some field like: "I met a great chick. Date(which was set to tomorrow morning) didn't went that great though." This is just a sample, but I hope you get what is problematic here. Consider using some better tool for parsing the JSON, e.g. gson, which will do most of the heavy-lifting for you and only thing for you will be actually using correct regex to get the date from the field.

Answer (score 2):

Well I hope that you find this usefull:

```
public static Date JsonDateToDate(String jsonDate)
{
    //  "/Date(1321867151710+0100)/"
    int idx1 = jsonDate.indexOf("(");
    int idx2 = jsonDate.indexOf(")") - 5;
    String s = jsonDate.substring(idx1+1, idx2);
    long l = Long.valueOf(s);
    return new Date(l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work For Sure

```
String date = "/Date(1376841597000)/";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String datereip = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(datereip);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm tt"));//It Will Be in format 29-OCT-2014 2:26 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static  String ConvertJsonDate()
          {

            String jsondate="\/Date(1427959670000)\/";
              jsondate=jsondate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
                long time = Long.parseLong(jsondate);
                Date d= new Date(time);
            Log.d("Convertd date is:"+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(d).toString());

                return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(d).toString();
          }
```