# Convert date in proper format in android

Tags: java, android, json, datetime, gson

```
"comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "created_time": "\/Date(1413140597000+0000)\/",
              "from": {
                "Id": "100000805164684",
                "Name": "Abid Raza",
                "photoUrl": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/100000805164684\/picture"
              },
              "like_count": "0",
              "message": "This is the unpredictable Boys ...!!!!"
            },
            {
              "created_time": "\/Date(1413141137000+0000)\/",
              "from": {
                "Id": "100000525438646",
                "Name": "Saim Ahmad",
                "photoUrl": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/100000525438646\/picture"
              },
              "like_count": "2",
              "message": "..."
            },
            {
              "created_time": "\/Date(1413141351000+0000)\/",
              "from": {
                "Id": "1672606457",
                "Name": "Muhammad Ghufran Siddiqui",
                "photoUrl": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/1672606457\/picture"
              },
              "like_count": "1",
              "message": "At-least we enjoyed :)"
            }
          ]
        }
```

This is my json string from the web service it contains created_time field. Which is in a weird format and not mapping on my java class using GSON Library. Now I want to store it in s string then cast it into date time format. Is that possible? Because I'm unable to understand this format. May be this is unix time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json DateTime Parsing In Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036075/json-datetime-parsing-in-android). It's UNIX time + timezone.

Comment: it is wrong date. It is server issue it looks like server returning a date function of mysql. Rather output of that date function. So contact webservice developer to resolve this

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I was doing this wrong in Service. Thanks